# required field error not appearing

Tags: php

When using this code to try an show an error, the page redirects to myaccount, but should only redirect there if the required field has been completed, for example;

error message appears if birth_country is not chosen

```
if(empty($birth_country))
    {
        $err[] = "ERROR - Enter Birth Country";
           header("Location: personal.php?msg=$err[0]");
    }
```

but if it is chosen, should redirect to...

```
header("location: myaccount.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']. "");
exit();
```

However it always goes to myaccount no matter what
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Frits says, you will have to print out the error to the screen if you want it to be seen; however, you can not print out any HTML before a `header` or the `header` won't work.  If you want to print the error on the redirecting page then I would suggest putting the error message in a `$_SESSION` cookie, then call and `echo` that cookie/variable on the redirecting page.  But by doing this, you will need to use `php session_start()` at the top of the question page and the top of your redirect page in order to use the `$_SESSION` variables

Also, your second `header`

```
header("location: myaccount.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']. "");
exit();
```

Should look like this:

```
header("Location: myaccount.php?id=$_SESSION['user_id']")
```

By using the double quotes, you don't need to add the `$_SESSION[]` tag, then add blank `""` at the end.

Comment: when using your recommended header, my PHPSTORM says that error around the code

Answer (score 1):

After your first header put `exit` as well. Your code just continues on and it likely emits the second location header as well, negating the first.

Comment: I get the error in the URL bar not on screen `http://localhost/euisample/personal.php?msg=ERROR%20-%20Enter%20Birth%20Country`

Comment: Yes, well that is what you're doing, putting the error in the URL. If you want to show it on the screen you have to get it out :P Something like `echo $_GET['msg']`